# How much power does a stepper motor draw when holding weight?

Tags: electrical-engineering, stepper-motor

I want to lift something in the air with a stepper motor. If the object is 1kg and I want to keep it in the air for 12 hours. Is it a good idea to keep the power on the motor all that time? Will it draw excessive amount of power? Ideally I would like to cut power to the motor when the movement is done, but then, will the motor be able to hold its position?

Comment: Hold it with a clamping device ie some type of brake, not the motor.

Comment: if you do this make sure the motor is rated for such continuous duty.

Comment: What is relevant is not the weight but the torque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how much weight and the motor.

Some stepper motors have detent torque. This is the torque they will hold without consuming any power.

They also have a holding torque for which you need to supply power.

The most fool-proof solution is to use a external brake.